# Innapropriate tags

Tags: support, tags

I saw a lot of tags that don't make any sense on stackoverflow, many don't even have a description. 
How these should be handled? Is there a functionality like flag for questions?

Comment: Bring it up on meta. If it's really awful so that there's no question it's a bad tag, you can manually edit all its posts removing the tag. Tags which have no questions are automatically removed by the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the per-site meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com in this case), and suggest that the tag be burninated. You tag the question with [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request). Of the 4 required tags ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), "discussion" is normally the one to use - the community will have a discussion about whether the tag really needs to go.

When suggesting that a tag be removed, make a good case - explain why the tag isn't helpful.
Some tags are even actively harmful, if they are about an off-topic subject. For example, recommendations of off-site resources are off-topic on SO and most other SE sites. So a tag about recommendations is usually a bad one - the existence of the tag suggests that it's OK to ask these things, when in reality it's not.

As @bjb568 points out in his comment, if a tag has no questions it will be automatically removed by the system.

If the tag does make sense, but doesn't have a description, by all means provide it! (Just don't copy off of Wikipedia or the web page of a product - provide some original content, and provide links to sources if applicable).

The full details for destroying tags are also on meta.stackoverflow.com: [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)